# Unable to append a dropdown list with a static option

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following script inside my Razor view engine :-

```
else if ($("#ChoiceTag").prop("checked")) {
                    $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Switch/LoadCSTag")",
                    function (CSData) {
                        var select = $("#GeneralCSID");
                        select.empty();
                        select.append($("<option/>", {
                            value: null
                        }));
                        $.each(CSData, function (index, itemData) {

                            select.append($('<option/>', {
                                value: itemData.Value,
                                text: itemData.Text
                            }));
                            select.val('@Model.Switch.ConsoleServerID');
                        });
                    });
                }
```

I was expecting that once the Jquery function runs, to append the  `"<option/>"` option inside the dropdown, but currently an empty record will be displayed at the beginning of the drop down list, instead of the `"<options>"` text.
Can anyone advice what might be the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: can you explain again what you are looking for

Comment: i am looking foe displaying the following text "<option/>" at the beginning of the dropdown list

Comment: @johnG: If you want it at the beginning instead of the end, use `prepend()` instead of `append()`.

Comment: Secondly, the appending (or prepending) will only be done if the `getJSON(` call is executed. Are you sure you are making that call to the backend? Else, your selectlist will remain empty (unless it had some default contents on page load)

Comment: but currently i am not getting the <option/> text any where, intead i am reveving an empty option..

Comment: yes i am making that call and the drop down will be populated with the json data..

Comment: Give me a second, writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select.append($("<option/>", {
   value: null
}));
```

This is your addition of the dummy option in the selectlist.

But you never specified what text should be displayed on that item. You can set it the exact same way you already set the text property of the items below (which, as per your comment, are already loaded correctly)

```
select.append($("<option/>", {
   value: "", //I prefer an empty string, not sure if null is valid
   text: "Select an option..."
}));
```

**Update**

Your quote:

```
displayed at the beginning of the drop down list, instead of the "<options>" text
```

I don't know what you mean by `"<options>" text`. Do you literally mean to put the string `<options>` as the text of that static option? I used `"Select an option..."` as an example, but you can choose any string you want.

Comment: thanks for the reply, my dropdown is of type int? , and when i added value & text, i start receiving the following error "General d must be a number" incase i did not select any value .. not sure what is causing this problem ..

Comment: but if i chnage the value from null to "" it will work well ,, can you advice , why i am getting this behavior ?

Comment: `"General d must be a number"` is not a default javascript/jquery error message as far as I know. This is either client-side validation (a developer chose to throw that message), or another framework that requires the selected value of the selectlist to be castable to int. `"General d must be a number" incase i did not select any value` ==> That seems to confirm my suspicion that there is *something* checking if the selected value of the selectlist is valid, and throwing that error when it isn't. I have no information on the rest of your application, so I can't help you there, unfortunately.

Comment: yes this error is generated from the entity framework , but long? should accept a null , but not an empty string .. this what i can not understand..

Comment: If you pass null as a value, you will get the following HTML: `<option value="">Your text</option>`. It is important to note: **the value of a dropdownlist is always a string**. If it's the string `"12345"` however, that can, at a later point, be converted to an int if you so choose. I'm assuming you use MVC? The modelbinder can do it for you. Or if you post back that value (e.g. in the parameter `string mySelectedValue`), you can convert using `long? converted = mySelectedValue as string;` If the string cannot be converted correctly (e.g. an empty string), `null` will be returned as the value

Comment: However, if you need further help with this, ask it in a different question. The original problem has been solved, and you new question will need more information regarding your MVC backend and how you handle your posted values in the controller methods.

Comment: @johnG: I only just now noticed that my code snippet in the previous comment is wrong, it should be `long? converted = mySelectedValue as long? ;`. You need to cast it to a `long?`, not a `string` :)